# Where to implement my function when using map for iteration?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

To iterate and add views dynamically from array, I'm using following code.

```
export default class CreateFeedPost extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedImages: ["1", "2", "3"]
    };
  }

  render() {
    let animation = {};
    let color = Platform.OS === "android"
      ? styleUtils.androidSpinnerColor
      : "gray";
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "column" }}>
        <View style={styles.topView}>
          <View style={styles.closeButtonView}>
            <TouchableHighlight
              underlayColor="transparent"
              style={styles.closeButton}
              onPress={this._closeButtonClicked.bind(this)}
            >
              <Icon name="times" color="#4A4A4A" size={20} />
            </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.postButtonView}>
            <TouchableHighlight
              underlayColor="transparent"
              style={styles.postButton}
              onPress={this._postButtonClicked.bind(this)}
            >
              <Text style={styles.postButtonText}>Post</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.profileContainer}>
          <View style={{ width: 65, height: 65, padding: 10 }}>
            <Image
              source={{ uri: global.currentUser.USER_PROFILE_PIC }}
              style={styles.profileImage}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={[styles.middleTextView]}>
            <Text style={[styles.memberName]}>
              {global.currentUser.USER_NAME}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
        <Animated.ScrollView
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          scrollEventThrottle={1}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          {...animation}
        >
          <View>
            <TextInput
              ref="postTextInputRef"
              placeholder="So, What's up?"
              multiline={true}
              autoFocus={true}
              returnKeyType="done"
              blurOnSubmit={true}
              style={styles.textInput}
              onChangeText={text => this.setState({ text })}
              value={this.state.text}
              onSubmitEditing={event => {
                if (event.nativeEvent.text) {
                  this._sendCommentToServer(event.nativeEvent.text);
                  this.refs.CommentTextInputRef.setNativeProps({ text: "" });
                }
              }}
            />
          </View>
        </Animated.ScrollView>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding">
          <ScrollView
            ref={scrollView => {
              this.scrollView = scrollView;
            }}
            style={styles.imagesScrollView}
            horizontal={true}
            directionalLockEnabled={false}
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            decelerationRate={0}
            snapToInterval={100}
            snapToAlignment={"start"}
            contentInset={{
              top: 0,
              left: 0,
              bottom: 0,
              right: 0
            }}
          >

            {this.state.selectedImages.map(function(name, index) {
              return (
                <View style={styles.imageTile} key={index}>
                  <View style={styles.imageView}>
                    <TouchableHighlight
                      underlayColor="transparent"
                      style={styles.imageRemoveButton}
                      onPress={() => this._imageRemoveButtonClicked.bind(this)}
                    >
                      <Icon name="times" color="#4A4A4A" size={20} />
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                  </View>
                </View>
              );
            })}
          </ScrollView>

          <TouchableHighlight
            underlayColor="transparent"
            style={styles.cameraButton}
            onPress={this._cameraButtonClicked.bind(this)}
          >
            <View style={styles.cameraButtonView}>
              <Icon name="camera" color="#4A4A4A" size={20} />
              <Text style={styles.cameraButtonText}>Add Pic</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </View>
    );
  }

  _closeButtonClicked() {
    this.props.navigator.pop();
  }

  _postButtonClicked() {}

  _cameraButtonClicked() {
    this.props.navigator.push({
      title: "All Photos",
      id: "photoBrowser",
      params: {
        limit: 3,
        selectedImages: this.state.selectedImages
      }
    });
  }

  _imageRemoveButtonClicked() {
    console.log("yes do it");
  }
}
```

I'm loading code in the render method. If I write the function **imageRemoveButtonClicked** outside render method, it's giving an error saying that **'Cannot read property bind of undefined'**. Don't know what to do. Can some one please help me in this.

Comment: Can you please share whole code so I can look into it

Comment: Yeah, sure. I'm updating

Comment: What do you mean by "outside the render method"?

Comment: imageRemoveButtonClicked function if I write outer side of render method, it's showing error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are not using an arrow function as the argument to `this.state.selectedImages.map()`. If you want to access `this` inside an inner function, you should use the arrow function syntax. The standard syntax does not capture `this`.

```
this.state.selectedImages.map((name, index) => {
   return (...);
})
```

Comment: Understood. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Use arrow functions and class property feature. For more information about  binding patterns read this [article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56). Try to add your method as:

```
export class App extends Component {
 yourMapFunction = () => {
  yourCode...
 }
}
```

Comment: Understood. Thank you :)